# Validating -moz-border-radius / -webkit-border-radius

Tags: css, validation, webkit, mozilla, w3c-validation

is there any way to validate -moz-border-radius / -webkit-border-radius in the CSS validator?

The client wants validation buttons in the sidebar (ugh!) and I can't find any way to bypass it. I've used @import too, no success.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889724/how-to-validate-moz-border-radius-webkit-border-radius

Comment: Possible? How about almost word-for-word duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-moz- and -webkit- aren't going to validate. They are vendor specific. When CSS3 becomes more 'offical', the actual border-radius should validate fine. Remember that there are several jQuery plugins that can round borders, but I highly recommend against them.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [PrefixFree](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/), you can use non-prefixed properties in your stylesheet and it'll convert them to prefixed properties (if necessary) for the appropriate browsers. This means in your stylesheet, you can write, for example, `border-radius: 5px;` (which will validate as CSS3), but older versions of Firefox and Safari will automatically use `-moz-border-radius: 5px;` and `-webkit-border-radius: 5px;`.