# How can W3C CSS Validator identify a css3 document?

Tags: css, doctype, w3c-validation

I'm having a issue!

Is there a way to identify a css3 file for the W3C validator?

In the HTML5 we put `<!DOCTYPE html>` but in a CSS file what can we put?

When I validate my css file and it contains some css3 elements (`@font-face`, `box-shadow`, etc), it says that it's not valid! 'cause it doesn't know it's css3. So... is there a method?

Thanks so much. Davide.

Comment: For why it doesn't default to CSS3, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041008/css-border-radius-validation-errors

Answer (score 5):

No, CSS files have no self-identification feature. To validate a file against a particular version of CSS, you have to explicitly choose what version you want. In the W3C Validator, this can be chosen from the “Profile” menu under “More options”.

CSS Level 3 is there, for what it's worth; until all CSS3 Modules are complete (don't hold your breath!) it's debatable what this really means...

Answer (score 1):

James code broke because he didn't enclose it in code tags but here is the actual code

```
http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yourwebsitename.com%2F
```

However, this will break your W3C Markup Validation.

```
cannot generate system identifier for general entity "usermedium"

…/css-validator/validator?profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&la…

general entity "usermedium" not defined and no default entity

…/css-validator/validator?profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&la…

reference not terminated by REFC delimiter

…ator/validator?profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en&uri=…

reference to external entity in attribute value

…ator/validator?profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en&uri=…

reference to entity "usermedium" for which no system identifier could be generated

…ator/validator?profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en&uri=…

cannot generate system identifier for general entity "warning"

…validator?profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en&uri=http%…
```

I do find it strange that code generated by the W3C CSS validation service breaks the W3C Markup service. LOL

So pick your poison.  I'm sticking with W3C Markup Validation. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the folling link with your URL in place of the question (???) marks:

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en&uri=http%3A%2F%2F???