# -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); not passing CSS3 Validator

Tags: css

How can I either make this pass CSS3 Validation or do the equivalent without this code. Heres the link to the validator:

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=reddurrant.com&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

and heres the code in one instance, (its used a few times)

```
#container{
    width:640px;
    height:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:5px solid #fff;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;  
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-moz-box-shadow` is not a valid CSS3 property. It is a vendor extension that was added to Mozilla-browsers so people could use it before it became standard.

Comment: yeah thats right. All major browsers now support the actual css box-shadow definition so you can just use that for any of the current browsers

Comment: To be clear, vendor extensions are in the specification and allowed  but will be flagged as errors. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#vendor-keywords

Comment: @Rob: They're in the grammar, but they won't validate as standard CSS. You can have the validator raise warnings instead of errors when encountering vendor extensions, though; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8470345/106224).

Comment: @BoltClock Yes. That's what I said.