# Validating -moz-box-sizing

Tags: css, validation, firefox

I am using box-sizing with vendor prefixes, like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

...running it through the [CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

...and getting this error:
**Property -moz-box-sizing doesn't exist : border-box**

Is there a way to make it pass?

Many thanks.

Comment: No, there isn't. Ignore the "error" and move on - the W3C validator is extremely picky, and doesn't acknowledge any sort of "exception" or "extention". If it's not in the official standards documentation, it's not valid.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to validate vendor prefixes in CSS like -webkit- and -moz-?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889724)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to validate vendor prefixes in CSS like -webkit- and -moz-?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889724/how-to-validate-vendor-prefixes-in-css-like-webkit-and-moz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. CSS3 is in BETA mode, browsers need to have prefixes because some properties have different values. In the future this will be one standard, the W3C CSS level 3 standard. Then the prefixes will be removed.

However, we need to use prefixes today and prefixes aren't really CSS, they are just an indicator for a browser which of the properties it will parse. And because they aren't CSS the CSS validator wouldn't pass.

But a 'valid' page doesn't say anything. Don't worry about some errors in your CSS/HTML, fix only the ones who are critical.

Comment: @Christoph well you are correct. But FF12 and IE10 are going the right way, gradients and a lot more get unprefixed!

Answer (score 0):

As Browservendors try to implement the new css features, they add prefixes, as long as they are not 100% conform to the css-standard. These vendor-prefixes are not part of the official CSS-specification and thus produce errors when run through the css-validator.

However, you could try [PrefixFree](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/) if you are absolutely keen on having standard-conform css.

Comment: Thanks for both responses. Much appreciated. I will have a look at PrefixFree. Many thanks.

Comment: @user1549184 you are welcome. One sidenote though: try to avoid w3chools as your primary source for education, they have a lot of errors and even false information. Check out http://w3fools.com/ - the section "WHAT" contains a list of some very good resources, where you can get reliable, up-to-date information. Personally I prefer MDN.