# css3 validation error for keyframes

Tags: css

I having an issue that while using @keyframes in css and checking that in css3 validation it was showing the error `"Sorry, the at-rule @-webkit-keyframes is not implemented"` like this. I think whether i need to add pre declaration like the css . Because i am new to create an animation using keyframes. Could anyone please provide me the details?

My code is,

```
@-webkit-keyframes roll{
    0% {-webkit-transform: translateX(500px) rotate(360deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes roll{
    0% {-moz-transform: translateX(500px) rotate(360deg); opacity: 0;}
    100% {-moz-transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg); opacity: 1;}
}
@-o-keyframes roll{
    0% {-o-transform: translateX(500px) rotate(360deg); opacity: 0;}
    100% {-o-transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg); opacity: 1;}
}
@-ms-keyframes roll{
    0% {-ms-transform: translateX(500px) rotate(360deg); opacity: 0;}
    100% {-ms-transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg); opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes roll{
    0% {transform: translateX(500px) rotate(360deg); opacity: 0;}
    100% {transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg); opacity: 1;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveUp{
    0% {-webkit-transform: translateY(40px);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: translateY(0px);}
}
@-moz-keyframes moveUp{
    0% {-moz-transform: translateY(40px);}
    100% {-moz-transform: translateY(0px);}
}
@-o-keyframes moveUp{
    0% {-o-transform: translateY(40px);}
    100% {-o-transform: translateY(0px);}
}
@-ms-keyframes moveUp{
    0% {-ms-transform: translateY(40px);}
    100% {-ms-transform: translateY(0px);}
}
@keyframes moveUp{
    0% {transform: translateY(40px);}
    100% {transform: translateY(0px);}
}
```

Comment: That's not a validation **error** it's an advisory and safely ignored. Remember, if your site **works** validation is basically irrelevant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to validate vendor prefixes in CSS like -webkit- and -moz-?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889724/how-to-validate-vendor-prefixes-in-css-like-webkit-and-moz)

Answer (score 1):

Vendor-specific prefixes are not part of W3C specifications. This is why @keyframes is valid but @-moz-keyframes and @-webkit-keyframes are not.

In this case it is safe to ignore these warnings but generally speaking, validators are pretty useful when developing cross-browser applications.

It may be helpful for you to use a CSS extension language such as [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) (if you're not using it already) that, with the help of some frameworks, can handle vendor prefixes for you.