# Can we have css style attribute more than once?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

```
#my_div{
  width: -moz-max-content;  /* mozila browser support */
  width : -webkit-max-content;  /*chrome and safari browser support*/
}
```

This code is working for my style.But I am not sure about whether its legal or not.
Is it a correct way to specify width depending upon browser type?

Comment: second one will overwrite with first one. Is it working separately for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's ok. Let's assume we use Mozilla browser. First `width` takes effect, than css parser reads second `width`, checks it's value as `-webkit-max-content;`, and for Mozilla browser it's not valid, so it's ignored and falling back to previous `width`, that is `width: -moz-max-content;`. Chrome will ignore first `width` for Mozilla browser.

Example of these attribute values may be find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, as depending on the browser used the style will take the only style which works with it.

Here is an example for a linear gradient in background

```
background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #207cca 51%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(50%,#2989d8), color-stop(51%,#207cca), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Answer (score 0):

They are property values, not attributes. They are both invalid, i.e. they do not conform CSS specifications. They are still the way to go if you wish to use such features; cf. [How to validate vendor prefixes in CSS like -webkit- and -moz-?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889724/how-to-validate-vendor-prefixes-in-css-like-webkit-and-moz)

Note that these settings has any effect on browsers that do not recognize either of the browser-prefixed values. The width would thus be determined by other CSS settings, or ultimately browser defaults. Therefore, consider putting some suitable “fallback” setting before these settings.