# Bootstrap css errors in the console

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I downloaded the boostrap.min.css version from [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download). But in the console its showing me a lot of errors. Check the image:[image]

Im using mozilla firefox up to date. It is weird that in chrome i don't have these erros. Is there a way to solve this bugs from boostrap or at least to hide it ? 
The first erros appears here :

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0,#e0e0e0 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0,#e0e0e0 100%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#fff),to(#e0e0e0));
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff 0,#e0e0e0 100%);
```

But i don't know what is wrong with this.

Comment: I think that you have these errors cause you're using firefox. I mean, -webkit and -o are for chrome and opera browsers, maybe that's why firefox sees them as "errors" but chrome dosn't. The same for filters - filters it's used for old IE versions

Comment: ok, but i don't believe that bootstrap did not solve that problem. It is weird because i downloaded from there website

Comment: It is not a real "problem". I mean, if you want cross browser compatibility, that's how you have to do. They are annoying, but that's it. They will not cause any problem at all, so don't worry :)

Comment: I know it is not a real problem. it is an esthetic problem. I really don't like that it showing me more than 100 lines of erros in mozilla console. I am asking you guys if it is a method to hide it or solve it , or do something :) I don't want to make the idea that there is nothing to do with this.

Comment: have a look here for a better explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889724/how-to-validate-vendor-prefixes-in-css-like-webkit-and-moz , and follow @Sandeeproop suggestion to hide them:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap has added vendor prefixes in css for cross browser support. Here `-webkit-` is for webkit engine (chrome, safari) and `-o-` is for opera.
the `-webkit-gradient` rule is a bit old and was later replaced by `-webkit-linear-gradient`.
The errors are there because, firefox does not recognize the webkit or opera prefixes. The errors can be ignored and they are to implement css3 experimental features maintaining cross browser issues.

Comment: Is there not a way for bootstrap to *not* display them?  Probably not, eh?

Answer (score 4):

The error messages you can see in console is actually warnings.
In firefox debugger if you go to css dropdown in console tab, you can see warning option is checked.
If you uncheck this option all these error messages will disappear.