# how to change css rain effect to jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I had created a rain effect which I want to change to work only in jquery, as when I try to validate css I got an error.

https://jsfiddle.net/sub7spc0/

```
Sorry, the at-rule @-webkit-keyframes is not implemented. 
Sorry, the at-rule @-moz-keyframes is not implemented.
```

How can I get the same rain effect via jquery only.

Comment: Where you want to use `jquery`?

Comment: Does CSS shows errors? where?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate vendor prefixes in CSS like -webkit- and -moz-?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889724/how-to-validate-vendor-prefixes-in-css-like-webkit-and-moz) // Rewriting something that is working to use a completely different technique for validation’s sake only is rather nonsense. Validation is a tool meant to help you, but not restrict you. As long as you know _why_ it results in warnings (or even errors), you can safely ignore them in cases like this (specifically regarding vendor prefixes.)

Comment: `How can I get the same rain effect via jquery only` If you check your CPU usage, you'll see it is already quite intensive using CSS. Doing that kind of animation in jQuery only can only be worst